# Making page number as a clickable hyperlink

Tags: hyperref, header-footer

Currently, I am able to get page number on the top right/left corner of a page. I am only focusing on PDF version of my thesis and I would like this page number to be a clickable link. I mean the reader should be able to click on the page number to open a website. The url of the website should have the pagenumber as a parameter. Something like - http://mysite.com/mythesis.php?pageno=123

Is that possible?

thank you!

Comment: sure, you only need to add the href command to the header definition.

Comment: Of course, if you did not initially set up your header, you will have to dig into the your (possibly university provided) .cls file and look for things line \@oddhead and \@evenhead.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to do it like this - \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\href{http://abc.com/xyz.php?sn=\thesubsection &pn=\thepage}{\thepage}}

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in comments